# Highcharts export server fails after a few seconds

Tags: tomcat, highcharts

We've just setup a Tomcat export server, and it works fine for the first few previews, then random things happen. Very rarely it works, mostly we get a blank image, sometimes "Error: Internal server error", occasionally "Error: error".

We enabled the logging, but that didn't say anything useful, only the parameters posted when we got "Internal server error", but the parameters are always the same (the defaults).

As soon as there is an error we need to restart the server, and then it works again for about 20 seconds.

Any ideas on what's happening, or how we can fix it?

Comment: Have you set up export server as instructed in [Docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

1. You set JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME AND CATALINA_HOME accurately
2. check you set properly URIEncoding="UTF-8"
3. Also check your deployment descriptor

Cheers!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really use Java/Tomcat/Phantom or anything like that, but to me these all sound like things that would cause an immediate failure (had issues with JAVA_HOME in that past) , rather than ones after time.

Comment: Set your JAVA_HOME and check if this is fixed or not. I'll be more than happy to assist you if you still have any problem.

Comment: Yeah JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are all set correctly. We just restarted it again, first 2 charts rendered, then we got errors and blank images back.

Comment: Can you please copy paste here $TOMCAT_HOME/log/catalinaout.log also check your images path.

Comment: have you fixed your problem or not?